# Dart get sub-generic type

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I try escape from mention of duplicate types
for example we have next two generic classes

```dart
class Test1<E extends Enum> {
  const Test1(this.element);

  final E? element;
}

class Test2<T extends Test1<E>, E extends Enum> {
  const Test2(this.tester);

  final T tester;

  E? test() { 
    return tester.element;
  }
}

enum TestE {
  oneCase,
  otherCase,
}

/// As can we see here we specified type [TestE] twice for [Test2].
/// it looks unnecessary, overhead.
final maintTest = (){
  const t1 = Test1<TestE>(TestE.oneCase);
  const t2 = Test2<Test1<TestE>,TestE>(t1);
  
  final TestE? result = t2.test();
  
  return result;
};
```

so I try to find a way - how I can get sub generic class without duplicate.

```dart
/// Some like this
class Test2<T extends Test1> {
  const Test2(this.tester);

  final Test1<E> tester;

  T.E? test() { // or T::E 
    //or something else 
    //but I believe we should be able specified [E] type from [T]
    return tester.element;
  }
}

/// And then we will can do it like this
final maintTest = (){
  const t1 = Test1<TestE>(TestE.oneCase);
  const t2 = Test2<Test1<TestE>>(t1);

  final TestE? result = t2.test();

  return result;
};
```

Comment: something like `class Test2<T extends Test1> {
  const Test2(this.tester);
  final Test1 tester;
  test() => tester.element;
}`?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh That would make `test` return `dynamic`.

Comment: aha, that's right @jamesdlin, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, I think that it's not possible**. I'm not aware of any mechanism that allows you to access the generic type(s) of a generic type.

When you define `T extends Type1`, `T` actually resolves to an instance of `Type` which is the runtime representation of your Type `T`.

This feature would require a certain level of intelligence and features from the compiler to implicitly infer and modify the `Type` interface for each type declaration, which is somewhat related to [Static Metaprogramming](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1482).